# SQL code in php not deleting record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

First:
Yes mysqli is awesome, i cannot use it for this.

now:
I wrote a code that once called should delete a specific record, it executes, no errors, and output message even comes out but it does not delete the record.

why? How can I fix this?

I see no mistake so far:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Delete']))
{ 
 $connection = mysql_connect("Deleted login info");

 // Check connection
 if (!$connection)
 {
 //echo "Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error();
 }   
 else
 { 
   //select a database
   $dbName="Katz";
   $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbName, $connection); 
        
   //confirm connection to database
   if (!$db_selected)
   {
     die ('Can\'t use $dbName : ' . mysql_error());
   }   
   else if ($_POST[KittenID]=='')
   { 
  $OutputMessage = 'Must add a Kitten-ID';
   }      
   else
   {//exeption else  
     {//main else
        $sql = "DELETE FROM Kittenzz WHERE KittenID='$_POST[KittenID]";

        $retval = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
        if(!$retval )
        {
   $OutputMessage = 'RECORD DOES NOT ALLOW DELETION';
        }
        $OutputMessage = 'RECORD DELETED';
    
        mysql_close($connection);            
   }//main else
    }//exception else
  } 

  mysql_close($connection);
}
   
?>
```

Could I get a fresh look from someone?

Comment: Please stop using the **deprecated** `mysql` API. Take a look at `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. And if you still wish to keep on using the deprecated api, for the love of something, sanitise your user input. Your script is open to SQL-injections!

Comment: Professor wants mysql, what am I to do fail the class?

Comment: No, if anything, you should ask your professor why he recommends a bad and deprecated API. Are you sure hes after the api and not the database?

Comment: If your professor seriously force you to use the deprecated mysql api, then yes, fail the class, and choose another school. Cause your professor have no idea what hes teaching. And still, if you are going to use it, see to that your input is *properly escaped*.

Comment: He specifically told the class to use mysql only.

Comment: Contact him, ask if he was talking about the database `mysql` or the php api `mysql_*`. Ask if its okay to use `PDO` or `mysqli(mproved)`instead, cause the internet people told you that its a very bad idea to use a deprecated and potentially dangerous `API`, especially when there is new ones that fixes the issues. Did he tell you to escape input when he told you to use the deprecated API?

Comment: Of course it isn't realistic to fail the class - you can still learn things with this database library. However, I agree with @Jite - he may have specified the database engine (MySQL and not, say, PostgreSQL) but does not care about the library (MySQL, MySQLi, MySQL/PDO).

Comment: Bear in mind this code has a serious SQL injection vulnerability in it. It is rather depressing that 6 out of the 7 answers, including the accepted answer, replicate that security problem without mentioning it.

Comment: Its for an intro class, I am sure it will not be a problem. But just in case what is SQL injection?

Comment: @user3541786: [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is a security hole which allows an attacker to execute any SQL query s/he likes (ie get the entire database).

Comment: @waka well that would be bad...

Comment: @Jite I will tell him tomorrow when the assignment is due.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed one single quote in your query.

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM Kittenzz
         WHERE KittenID='$_POST[KittenID]";
```

Please try this :

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM Kittenzz
         WHERE KittenID='".$_POST['KittenID']."';";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just a question when i try to find the record later, I find it empty of values but I find it. Can I make it as if the record was never added?

Comment: @user3541786 : sorry but I'm not getting your 'this' question.

Comment: :Its ok my find method was broken and I thought it was finding deleted records.

Comment: This has a whacking great SQL injection vulnerability in it - we try to encourage posters to post secure code, or at least draw attention to the issue.

Answer (score 2):

What the others said, but also - your nesting is off. For example, the below nesting is not correct:

```
else
    { //exeption else       
        { //main else
```

You can't start the "main" there - the entire exception is wrapped in the main, or the main doesn't exist.

Either remove the starting and closing bracket for "main", or put a statement before it.

As per comments, apparently this is accepted/ignored in PHP. So replace my "can't" with "probably shouldn't, because it looks odd and serves no purpose".

Comment: Those are just my mental notes, its 3:30 AM its hard to concentrate, and i must finish this before class.

Comment: I don't care about the notes - the brackets "{" are out of place :)

Comment: The bracket scope wont make the code not run, but they are redundant. In lots of languages, the scoping would create a context, but in php, it don't matter.

Comment: @Jite I didn't know this. Maybe not the most productive answer then, but it sure does look odd to me.

Comment: Well, I still think your answer has a point, as you are pointing out that the clause has nothing to do with the `else`. Its just an anonymous scope, which in php is pretty useless. And yes, it does look odd. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `Kittenzz`
                        WHERE `KittenID`='".$_POST['KittenID']."'";
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the closing ' at the end of the delete sql. You also are not concatenating the $_POST[KittenID] variable but just sticking it at the end of the string. So:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM Kittenzz
                    WHERE KittenID='$_POST[KittenID]";
```

becomes:

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM Kittenzz
                    WHERE KittenID='" . $_POST[KittenID]. "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your code:

First change this:

```
if ($_POST[KittenID]=='')
```

to this:

```
if ($_POST['KittenID']=='')
```

and this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM Kittenzz WHERE KittenID='$_POST[KittenID]";
```

to this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM Kittenzz WHERE KittenID='" . $_POST['KittenID'] . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your query is missing a closing char \'.

yours:

```
 "DELETE FROM Kittenzz WHERE KittenID='$_POST[KittenID] ";
```

shoud be:

```
 "DELETE FROM Kittenzz WHERE KittenID='$_POST[KittenID]' ";
```

BTW: @vivek code is more elegant.

Cheers